# How can I left-and-right justify text in columns in Beamer?

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, columns

I have a slide like the following:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{two columns}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

How can I get the text in each of the columns to be justified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `\justifying` from `ragged2e` package.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
\frametitle{two columns}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \justifying
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
\end{column}
\hfill
\begin{column}[t]{.5\textwidth}
  \justifying
Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium.
\end{column}%
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I have also added the `[t]` option to `\begin{column}` so that the columns are aligned at top.

Comment: Ah, that's great. Thank you very much for your help and your thoughtful suggestion regarding vertical alignment.